# How do i seek with bass?

Tags: c#, .net, bass

I am using [Bass](http://www.un4seen.com/bass.html). How do i seek to the middle of the song or to any given point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var thetime = Bass.BASS_ChannelSeconds2Bytes(_stream, doubleInSeconds);
var success = Bass.BASS_ChannelSetPosition(_stream, thetime);
```